# How to create a new page with React js

Tags: reactjs

I have a code where this would essentially show links that you can press and would redirect you. I am have a problem where I am trying to click the link to "eco-news" and essentially open up a page with news articles in it. I have coded the news section, but I just dont know how to implement it.

Home > News > (directed to a new page where news would would populate)

```
import React from "react";
import './sidebar.css';
//import News from "../news section/News";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

// Imported Images ==============>
import logo from '../../Assets/logo.png';

// Imported icons ===============>
import {IoMdSpeedometer} from 'react-icons/io';
import {TfiWorld} from 'react-icons/tfi';
import {BsQuestionCircle} from 'react-icons/bs'

// placeholder logo image
const Sidebar = () => {
    return (
        <div className="sideBar grid">
            <div className="logoDiv flex">
                <img src={logo} alt="World Space Logo" /> 
                <h2>World Space.</h2>
            </div>

            <div className="menuDiv">
                <h3 className="divTitle">
                    CONSUMPTION OVERVIEW
                </h3>
                <ul className="menuLists grid">
                    <li className="listItem">
                        <a href="/#" className="menuLink flex">
                            <IoMdSpeedometer className="icon" />
                            <span className="smallText">
                                Readout
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li className="listItem">
                        <a href="/#" className="menuLink flex">
                            <TfiWorld className="icon" />
                            <span className="smallText">
                                Driven Equivalent
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li className="listItem">
                        <a href="/#" className="menuLink flex">
                            <TfiWorld className="icon" />
                            <span className="smallText">
                                Efficiency Score
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
{/* This is the tab for the Eco news, please update the necessary fonts and spacing */}
            <div className="menuDiv">
                <h3 className="divTitle">
                    NEWS
                </h3>
                <ul className="menuLists grid">
                    <li className="listItem">
                        {/* <a href=/News className="menuLink flex"> */}
                        <Link to ='\News' className="menuLink flex">
                            <TfiWorld className="icon" />
                            <span className="smallText">
                              <a href="/News.js">Eco-News</a>  
                            </span>
                        </Link>
                        {/* </a> */}
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div className="settingsDiv">
                <h3 className="divTitle">
                    SETTINGS
                </h3>
                <ul className="menuLists grid">
                    <li className="listItem">
                        <a href="/#" className="menuLink flex">
                            <IoMdSpeedometer className="icon" />
                            <span className="smallText">
                                Dashboard
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li className="listItem">
                        <a href="/#" className="menuLink flex">
                            <TfiWorld className="icon" />
                            <span className="smallText">
                                Consumption Overview
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li className="listItem">
                        <a href="/#" className="menuLink flex">
                            <TfiWorld className="icon" />
                            <span className="smallText">
                                Goals
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li className="listItem">
                        <a href="/#" className="menuLink flex">
                            <TfiWorld className="icon" />
                            <span className="smallText">
                                Achievements
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>

            <div className="sideBarCard">
                <BsQuestionCircle className="icon" />
                <div className="cardContent">
                    <h3>Help Center</h3>
                    {/*<p>Having trouble in World Space, please contact us.</p>
                    <button className="btn">Go to help center</button>*/}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Sidebar;
```

```
 <div className="menuDiv">
                <h3 className="divTitle">
                    NEWS
                </h3>
                <ul className="menuLists grid">
                    <li className="listItem">
                        {/* <a href=/News className="menuLink flex"> */}
                        <Link to ='\News' className="menuLink flex">
                            <TfiWorld className="icon" />
                            <span className="smallText">
                              <a href="/News.js">Eco-News</a>  
                            </span>
                        </Link>
                        {/* </a> */}
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

if you click the link it would lead to a broken page.

[What it looks like so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUFkt.png)

Comment: Can you share your App.js and index.js

Comment: Did you setup the route for `/News` in your Router?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have followed the below steps as pre requisites

1. [Create browser router](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-browser-router)
2. [Add a route for your `News` component](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route)

Only then will your routing work